# Parsing flat text file in Ruby Rake task

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, text

OK, I am giving this a shot.  There are a gazillion SO questions with answers for my question but none that solve my issue.

I am creating a rake task to parse a flat text file in RoR.  The file has a header but there are not any delimiters other than blank space.  So I was going to use the blank space as delimiter but it will not work.  Here is example of text file:

Name Birthdate
Bill 12/25/86
John Smith 1/1/87

If i use ' ' as a delimiter than I get the correct result for the first entry but not the second as there are 2 strings before the date and not just one.  Here is how I have been trying to do this:

```
File.open(file, "r").each do |line|
  name, birthdate = line.strip.split("")
  user = User.new(user_name: name, birth_date: birthdate)
  user.save
end
```

I cannot figure out how to deal with the fact that the first "field" may or may not be a single word.  Ultimately I would prefer to require csv and then my issue would not exist.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to change the format if possible but working with your two examples you could do something like this

```
components = line.split(' ')
date = components.pop
name = components.join(' ')
```

Comment: Yes your solution would work for the small example.  I am actually working with a file that has several columns.

Comment: Do any of the other columns have spaces in them? If not you can use the same technique popping of the values. If other columns have spaces then you need to sort out the input format

Comment: Um that is true.  Definitely doable although your first suggestion was best, change the format!